# Which is the correct key to modify to set a wireless password via nmcli

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

A number of answers describe how to modify properties of a wireless connection via nmcli (for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316482/16821).

However, I don't know how to determine which parameter I should modify. There seem to be several options wep-key[0-4] and psk.

I am able to connect to wifi with no problem by passing the --ask option and entering the password manually.

Which parameter(s) to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All modern WPA-secured Wi-Fi networks use the `psk` parameter.

> `nmcli> describe wifi-sec.psk`
>
> Pre-Shared-Key for WPA networks. For WPA-PSK, it's either an ASCII passphrase of 8 to 63 characters that is (as specified in the 802.11i standard) hashed to derive the actual key, or the key in form of 64 hexadecimal character. The WPA3-Personal networks use a passphrase of any length for SAE authentication.

The four `wep-key` parameters are only used for the *very* obsolete WEP security mechanism.

> `nmcli> describe wifi-sec.wep-key0`
>
> Index 0 WEP key.  This is the WEP key used in most networks.  See the "wep-key-type" property for a description of how this key is interpreted.

Comment: even when I set that parameter I still get a message that >> Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option. <<. I must have a different problem then. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: for some reason I am unable to accept your answer